# how can i run a single file class to test in my android project?

Tags: eclipse

I am new in android. I have built an project.

I have a class that check if the url exist or not like this:

```
public class connect {
Boolean checkServer() throws IOException
{
    Boolean check = false;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("www.google.com");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        connection.getInputStream();
                    // do something with the input stream here
        check = true;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        check = false;
    }
    finally {
        if(null != connection) { connection.disconnect(); }
    }
    return check;
}
```

}

And I want to run it as single file in eclipse.

How can I do this?

thank anyway

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
  Boolean check = checkServer();
  if (check)
  {
   System.out.println("thành công");
  }
 } but when i run, it show the message"aunching has encountered a problem cannot connect to vm" how could i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a Junit class or in a simple way, write a new class with public static void main() method or with in the same class and in main() method you should create an object of the class and launch the main() method

```
public class ConnectDemo {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connect c = new Connect();

        if(c.checkServer())
            System.out.println("Check Server Successful");
        else 
            System.out.println("Check Server not Successful");
    }

}
```